# When I run the shell doctrine:cache:clear-metadata for my project by symfony the redis key is very very big

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

When I run the shell doctrine:cache:clear-metadata for my project by symfony the redis key is very very big, the comment is

```
php app/frontend/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

the entity is cache by redis.but when I see the redis data by redis-cli . I find old metadata is exists. so , I think the cache data is continue largen . I'm very vorried.

Answer (score 3):

I see that this is not a new post but better later than never. The only thing that you need to do is to add --flush flag to your command:

```
php app/frontend/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --flush
```

That will delete the keys in the Redis database. If you are using more than 1 database and your entities are divided base on the connection, you can add entity manager flag which will specify the connection via entity manager name:

```
php app/frontend/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --flush --em=orm_default
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try running a similar script from the command line.

```
<?php

$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

$keys = $redis->keys("*");
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $key ."\n";
    $redis->del($key);
}
```

It might remove more than what is needed but it's been very useful to me.

For the record, this snippet is largely from another SO answer.